# Reload Javascript file on ajax reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

We are using WordPress website with online catalogue plug-in.
This plug-in use Ajax to reload page when using search or when browsing through categories.

The problem is that it does not reload one important JavaScript file which is required for our product buttons and enquiry basket which is connected to our booking system. This way we loose the product buttons once ajax reload page.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://d4lmxg2kcswpo.cloudfront.net/assets/store/booqable_v2.js?ver=2.0.0'></script>
```

How can I load again this code above once ajax is used please?

Thank you

Comment: AJAX is used to avoid reloading a page. It processes POST/GET in the background while keeping a client on the same page. Most people would update required variable(s)/Dom element(s) upon ajax success. If you intend to reload the page or the required page scripts then you might find the use of AJAX is pointless and would be just as well using a form to post/get the data and print/echo the results into the page upon reloading/rendering

Comment: "once ajax reload page"...ajax does not reload the page. When the ajax call returns, the Javascript code might remove part of the page and replace it with something else though, e.g. in order to display updated results. If it deletes and re-creates part of the DOM which includes this script tag...well then it's not coded very well. Should be no need to remove script tags when altering the page with the results of an ajax request.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replies. Yes I word it wrong, you are correct that Ajax does not reload page. My problem only is that when ajax load new data on the same page it loose one of the scripts (as in my first post). This is due that website use two plugins. One is online catalog for products which uses Ajax and second is plugin from our internal system which connects products between website and our internal booking system.